# Context menu binding with itemsource is not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

In a button I am trying to put context menu where I need to bind the header and the icon from the itemsource.
But this is not working out and giving some error at run time. Not able to figure out the issue.

```
<ContextMenu Width="Auto"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListofTransmitModes}"
             Placement="Top">
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem>
            <MenuItem.Header>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding ModeName}"/>
            </MenuItem.Header>
        <MenuItem.Icon>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image>
               <Image.Style>
                   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                       <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform" />
                       <Setter Property="Width" Value="17" />
                       <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,3,6,3"/>
                       <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="NearestNeighbor" />
                   <Style.Triggers>
                      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                          <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.24" />
                      </Trigger>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ModeName}" Value="{x:Static p:Resource.ANALOG_CLEAR}">
                         <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Motorola.APS.MMC.Common.Themes;component/Images/LMR/analog_clear.png" />
                      </DataTrigger>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ModeName}" Value="{x:Static p:Resource.ANALOG_CODED}">
                          <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Motorola.APS.MMC.Common.Themes;component/Images/LMR/analog_coded.png" />
                      </DataTrigger>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ModeName}" Value="{x:Static p:Resource.DIGITAL_CLEAR}">
                          <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Motorola.APS.MMC.Common.Themes;component/Images/LMR/digital_clear.png" />
                      </DataTrigger>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ModeName}" Value="{x:Static p:Resource.DIGITAL_CODED}">
                          <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Motorola.APS.MMC.Common.Themes;component/Images/LMR/digital_coded.png" />
                      </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
           </Image.Style>
        </Image>
     </DataTemplate>
     </MenuItem.Icon>
     </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>

   <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.TransmitModeSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
   </Style>
   </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
   </ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `ContextMenu` is displayed in a different visual tree to the rest of the UI. It therefore has no access to a `DataContext` from the main UI visual tree. For this reason, we have to use the `FrameworkElement.Tag` property and the [`ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to pass it through to the other visual tree. First, set the `DataContext` of the view, or whatever you want into the `Tag` property of the control that you are setting the `ContextMenu` on:

```
<Button Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={
    x:Type YourViewsXmlNamespace:YourView}}}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource Menu}" ... >
    ...
</Button>
```

Now you can access this through the `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` property:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListofTransmitModes}" Placement="Top"
    DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    ...
</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace yours with this,

```
       <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Width="Auto"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListofTransmitModes}"
                         Placement="Top">
                <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding ModeName}">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image>
                                    <Image.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                            <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform" />
                                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="17" />
                                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,3,6,3" />
                                            <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="NearestNeighbor" />
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.24" />
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ModeName}" Value="{x:Static p:Resource.ANALOG_CLEAR}">
                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Motorola.APS.MMC.Common.Themes;component/Images/LMR/analog_clear.png" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ModeName}" Value="{x:Static p:Resource.ANALOG_CODED}">
                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Motorola.APS.MMC.Common.Themes;component/Images/LMR/analog_coded.png" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ModeName}" Value="{x:Static p:Resource.DIGITAL_CLEAR}">
                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Motorola.APS.MMC.Common.Themes;component/Images/LMR/digital_clear.png" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ModeName}" Value="{x:Static p:Resource.DIGITAL_CODED}">
                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Motorola.APS.MMC.Common.Themes;component/Images/LMR/digital_coded.png" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Image.Style>
                                </Image>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.TransmitModeSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
                        <Setter Property="MenuItem.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
```